# .net core 2.1.5 and Entity Framework max pool size reached

Tags: .net, performance, entity-framework, .net-core

I a working on one .net core application where that application is maxing pool size out, version of .net core is 2.1.5 and EF is also version 2. max pool size is 1500

> "Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a
> connection from the pool. This may have occurred because all pooled
> connections were in use and max pool size was reached."

This specific API have lots of read-only queries so QueryTracking is set to noTracking is disabled and below is DBContext code looks like,

```
namespace Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection
{
    public static class Wireup
    {
        public static void WireUpClients(this IServiceCollection services, string ClientsDbConnectionString)
        {
            WireupCommon(services);

            services.WireUpCommonMutators();

            var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => { cfg.AddProfile<ClientsMappingProfile>(); });
            var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
            services.TryAddSingleton(new ClientsMapper(mapper));

            services.AddDbContext<ReplacementFieldsDbContext>(
                options => options.UseSqlServer(ClientsDbConnectionString));

            services.AddDbContext<ClientsDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(ClientsDbConnectionString));
            services.AddDbContext<NomenclaturesDbContext>(
                options => options.UseSqlServer(ClientsDbConnectionString));

            services.AddDbContext<ClientsCombinedDbContext>(
                options => options.UseSqlServer(ClientsDbConnectionString));

       ........
            services.TryAddTransient<IClientsImpactingReleasesHelper, ClientsImpactingReleasesHelper>();
        }

        public static void WireupCommon(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.WireUpCommonUtil(); // Should go first to inject IAmbientRelease
            services.WireUpCommonCore();
            services.WireUpCommonRepo();
            services.WireUpCommonServices();
            services.WireUpCommonComponents();
        }
    }
}
```

on database side saw many sleeping connections. Is there a way to identify which part of code causing this max pool and my understanding is EF should be managing connections is there any known bug in EF 2?

Controller

```
   public async Task<IEnumerable<CurrentBestPracticeRelease>> GetApprovedCurrentReleases(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return await _bestPracticesService.GetApprovedCurrent(cancellationToken);
        }
```

Service

```
   public async Task<IEnumerable<CurrentBestPracticeRelease>> GetApprovedCurrent(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {


            var versionsQuery = _clientsRepo.ApprovedCurrentClientVersions;
            var releases = await _clientHelper.MapReleases(versionsQuery, _translationHelper, cancellationToken);

            return _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<CurrentBestPracticeRelease>>(releases);
        }
```

Repository

```
namespace Clients.Repositories
{
    public class ClientsRepository<TEntity> : BaseRepository<ClientsDbContext>, IClientsRepository<TEntity>
        where TEntity : BaseClient, new()
    {

        private readonly bool _isBestPracticeRepo = typeof(TEntity) == typeof(BestPractice);
        private readonly IItemVersionValidator _itemVersionValidator;
        private readonly IApprovalHelper _approvalHelper;

        public ClientsRepository(ClientsDbContext context, IAmbientRelease ambientRelease,
            IItemVersionValidator itemVersionValidator, IApprovalHelper approvalHelper) : base(context)
        {
            _ambientRelease = ambientRelease;
            _itemVersionValidator = itemVersionValidator;
            _approvalHelper = approvalHelper;
        }

        //filter to BP or Client rows only 
        public IQueryable<ClientVersion> FilteredClientVersions => FilteredVersions();

        
        public IQueryable<ClientVersion> ClientVersions => _context.ClientVersions.Include(c => c.Client);

        public IQueryable<ClientVersion> CurrentClientVersions => FilteredCurrentVersions();

        public IQueryable<ClientVersion> ApprovedCurrentClientVersions => FilteredApprovedCurrentVersions();

        public async Task<ClientVersion> GetClientVersionWithRelatedData(Guid releaseKey, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
            => await _context.ClientVersions.Include(o => o.Client).Include(o => o.BestPractice)
            .Where(o => o.ReleaseKey == releaseKey).SingleOrDefaultAsync(cancellationToken);

        public IQueryable<NamedEntityOverTime> ClientNamesOverTime =>
            _context.ClientNamesOverTime.FromSql("SELECT * FROM [ClientNamesOverTime]");

        public async Task<ClientVersion> Create(ClientVersion clientVersion, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
             
            clientVersion.ClientId = clientVersion.Client?.ClientId ?? clientVersion.ClientId;
            clientVersion.Client = clientVersion.ClientId == 0 ? new TEntity() : null;

            await ValidateClientVersionCreate(clientVersion, cancellationToken);

            var entry = await _context.ClientVersions.AddAsync(clientVersion, cancellationToken);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
            return entry.Entity;
        }

        public async Task<ClientVersion> Update(ClientVersion clientVersion, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var entry = _context.ClientVersions.Update(clientVersion);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);

            return entry.Entity;
        }
 
        

        public async Task<bool> IsBestPractice(long clientId, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return (await _context.BaseClients.FirstAsync(bc => bc.ClientId == clientId)) is BestPractice;
        }

        private IQueryable<ClientVersion> FilteredCurrentVersions()
        {
            return _context.ClientVersions.Include(e => e.Client).FromSql("SELECT * FROM [CurrentClientVersion]")
                .Where(v => EF.Property<bool>(v.Client, "IsBestPractice") == _isBestPracticeRepo).AsQueryable();
        }

        private IQueryable<ClientVersion> FilteredApprovedCurrentVersions()
        {
            return _context.ClientVersions.Include(e => e.Client).FromSql("SELECT * FROM [ApprovedCurrentClientVersion]")
                .Where(v => EF.Property<bool>(v.Client, "IsBestPractice") == _isBestPracticeRepo).AsQueryable();
        }

        private IQueryable<ClientVersion> FilteredVersions()
        {
            return _context.ClientVersions
                .Where(v => EF.Property<bool>(v.Client, "IsBestPractice") == _isBestPracticeRepo).AsQueryable();
        }

        public async Task ValidateClientVersionCreate(ClientVersion version, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var versionQuery = _context.ClientVersions.Where(v => v.ClientId == version.ClientId);
            await _itemVersionValidator.ValidateUniqueReleaseDate(versionQuery, "Client", version.Name, cancellationToken);
        }

    }
}
```

please guide.

Updates: We are using repository pattern and In many places inside application using below where SQL is a raw SQL written directly as LINQ is difficult to add, do you think there is something specific i look into which can confirm if connection is not being leaked?

```
_context.BaseClients.FromSql(sql, releaseKeyParam, asOfParam, clientIdParam)
                .Select(c => c.ClientId).ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
```

Throwing that error for Clients.Repositories.ClientsDbContext -

```
An exception occurred in the database while iterating the results of a query for context type 'Clients.Repositories.ClientsDbContext'.
System.InvalidOperationException: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.
   at System.Data.Common.ADP.ExceptionWithStackTrace(Exception e)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenDbConnectionAsync(Boolean errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

Comment: There's no bug. The application is leaking connections and contexts. Where and how are those DbContext instances used? Are they ever disposed? What kind of application are you building? In a web application *every* HTTP request is a separate context so every DbContext instance injected into a controller through constructor injection is always disposed *by the ASP.NET Core middleware* when the action that handles the request exits. To exhaust the pool, your application is doing something else.

Comment: I'd guess that you don't use DbContext in a controller, or don't even have a web application. I suspect you create a new DbContext instance each time *without a scope* and never dispose it, leaving a *lot* of DbContext instances alive. Furthermore, I'd suspect you leave *transactions open*, otherwise the DbContext wouldn't keep any connections open. A DbContext only opens a transaction when reading data, when saving data with `SaveChanges` or when the code uses an explicit database transaction

Comment: Thank you for initial look let me add some more details @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: Post your code as text, not images. Images can't be copied, compiled, tested or googled

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos please see updated details - let me know if something else needed can help

Comment: The exception call stack should indicate which connection string is leading to connection pool exhaustion.  Audit the code for anywhere you use SqlConnection directly, or a DbContext that's not request-scoped (like a background thread).

Comment: Throwing that error for Clients.Repositories.ClientsDbContext

Answer (score 0):

First of all enable [DbContext pooling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/context-pooling)

Use the Right way to Implement ServiceCollection Extension Pattern, like this.

```
using ConfigSample.Options;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

namespace Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection
{
    public static class MyConfigServiceCollectionExtensions
    {
        public static IServiceCollection AddConfig(
             this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration config)
        {
            services.Configure<PositionOptions>(
                config.GetSection(PositionOptions.Position));
            services.Configure<ColorOptions>(
                config.GetSection(ColorOptions.Color));

            return services; // very important
        }
    }
}
```

[Register groups of services with extension methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-5.0#register-groups-of-services-with-extension-methods)

and I recommend you to update the project to .NET 5

Comment: Thank you for response - i tried adding it getting some error - let me find what else need to modify will update

"cannot be pooled because it does not have a single public constructor accepting a single parameter of type DbContextOptions."